# PHP smarty recursion?

Tags: php, smarty

I'm new to smarty templates but is it possible to do recursion in the actual template vs throughout a php custom smarty function?

Example please.

Any Advice appreciated!

Comment: This sounds like way to much work to be doing in a view ...

Answer (score 1):

See if this link helps you

http://www.smarty.net/forums/viewtopic.php?t=291

In short, it might be possible, but isn't the best idea. Recursion when not handled properly can lead to a lot of trouble and template engines aren't designed for recursion.

Answer (score 1):

You can do recursive templates through [{include}](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.include.tpl) and [{function}](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.function.tpl). For the latter, [Recursive menu {function} example](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.function.tpl#id403032) exitst.