# how to foreach an array variable created with recursive function in Smarty

Tags: php, recursion, foreach, smarty

I have an array which I created in php with a recursive function, I do not know how many dimensions, how can I use in Smarty ?

I trying use this code :

```
{foreach $myArr as $items}
    <li>
          {$items.title}
          {if $item.submenu}
                 <ul>
                 {foreach $items.submenu as $items2}
                     <li>{$items2.title}</li>
                 {/foreach}
                 </ul>
          {/if}
    </li>
{/foreach}
```

But this code is for just 2 levels, may be my array have 3 or 4 or ... levels.

**UPDATE:**

I found the solution, in my solution I use Smarty functions :

```
        {function name=menu level=0}
            <ul>
                {foreach $data as $items}
                    <li>
                        <a href="{$items.url}">
                            {$items.title}
                        </a>
                        {if is_array($items.submenu)}
                            {menu data=$items.submenu level=$level+1}
                        {/if}
                    </li>
                {/foreach}
            </ul>
        {/function}


{menu data=$menuItems}
```

Comment: possible duplicate [#1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/437862/what-is-the-best-way-to-handle-recursion-in-smarty) and [#2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9562709/php-smarty-recursion)

Comment: @PeterSzymkowski should I use plugin ? there is no any way to use with Smarty core ?

Comment: see my answer. didn't tested

Answer (score 0):

I would go a different approach.
My suggestion:
Instead of creating arrays with menus. Create two or one class/es.

First class is a Menu class which holds the items in a key/value manner.
Second class would be a menu item.

That way you could all necessary iterations/logic do through a function call in the model
and the printing in the view.

something like:

```
class Menu {

    protected $_items = array();
    protected $_parent_child = array();

    public function add_menu_item($name, $id, $parent_id) {
        if (array_key_exists($id, $this->_items))
            return;

        $this->_items[$i] = array('name' => $name, 'id' => $id, 'parent' => $parent_id) // model with data
        $this->_parent_child[$parent_id] = $this->_items[$id];
    }


    public function get_nodes_by_parent($id=null /*for root*/) {
        if (array_key_exists($id, $this->_parent_child))
            return $this->_parent_child[$id];

        return array(); // or null or something     
    }



}
```

Menu template:

```
{foreach($menuClass->get_nodes_by_parent() as $item ) {
    <ul>
        <li>{$item['name']}</li>
        {include 'sub_cats' id=$item['id'], menuclass=$menuclass}
    </ul>
{endforeach}
```

Sub category template:

```
{foreach($menuClass->get_nodes_by_parent($id) as $item ) {
    <ul>
        <li>{$item['name']}</li>
        {include 'sub_cats' id=$item['id']}
    </ul>
{endforeach}
```

This is not fully complete nor tested. But that would be my approach.

Comment: I don't get it even though that seems cleaner