# change recursive function from Php to smarty?

Tags: function, recursion, smarty3

my problem 
i have menu endless by this 
code

```
        $result=db::query_tpv("SELECT * FROM  tpv_link");
while($row = db::fetch_array($result,'assoc'))
 {

$menu[$row['parent_id']][$row['id_link']] = $row['name_link'];

}
function make_menu($parent_id)
{global $menu;if (!isset($menu[$parent_id])) {return;}
$nodes = $menu[$parent_id];
echo '<ul>';
foreach($nodes as $menu_id => $menu_name)
{
echo '<li>'.$menu_name ;
make_menu($menu_id) ;
echo '</li>';
}
echo '</ul>';
}
```

it's working in samrty as well by this {0|make_menu}
, but i want cancel this Function and change to this in smarty (define $menu)

```
{function name=menu level=0}
        <ul>
            {foreach $data as $items}
                <li>
                    <a href="{$items.url}">
                        {$items.title}
                    </a>
                    {if is_array($items.submenu)}
                        {menu data=$items.submenu level=$level+1}
                    {/if}
                </li>
            {/foreach}
        </ul>
    {/function}
{menu data=$menuItems}
```

at this [how to foreach an array variable created with recursive function in Smarty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14342645/how-to-foreach-an-array-variable-created-with-recursive-function-in-smarty)
but it's not work .....

Comment: What do you mean by "not work"?

Comment: i meant not appear nothing (any result)

Comment: please check my code and array

Comment: I don't know smarty, but where does the function get `$data` from? I'm assuming it isn't defined globally and you're trying to loop over something that isn't set. You should be using `error_reporting(-1)` to see any notices or warnings your code produces.

Comment: thanks i wil check now

Answer (score 0):

Hello I Find Solution after 3 days

Here

------------First You make Query You table----------
Ex:

```
    $result=db::query_tpv("SELECT * FROM  tpv_link");
  while($row = db::fetch_array($result,'assoc'))
 {

 $menu[]=$row ;
 }
```

------------Secound Uses This Function (For make Your pyrimd array)----------
------------  Note change id,parentid----------

```
   function buildTree(array $elements, $parentId = 0) {
$branch = array();

foreach ($elements as $element) {
    if ($element['parent_id'] == $parentId) {
        $children = buildTree($elements, $element['id_link']);
        if ($children) {
            $element['children'] = $children;
        }
        $branch[] = $element;
    }
}

return $branch;
}
```

-------------------Before Smarty Template--------------------

```
$tree = buildTree($menu);//$menu array all data From Query
$smarty->assign('menu',$tree);
```

------------------In smarty Template-------------------------

```
   {function name=menu level=0}
        <ul>
            {foreach $data as $items}
                <li>
                    <a href="{$items.url}">
                        {$items.name_link}
                    </a>
                    {if $items.children}
                        {menu data=$items.children level=$level+1}
                    {/if}
                </li>
            {/foreach}
        </ul>
    {/function}


    {menu data=$menu}
```